# Responsive design is enabled for Teams users

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, announcement, design

We've been actively working to make [Stack Overflow and network site pages responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes). As a part of that effort, we have now turned on responsive for anyone who is in a Stack Overflow team. This is a work in progress and this step is a part of our effort to validate our significant changes to page layout code.

Browsing the site for information will be improved on smaller viewports. See [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiZ6R.jpg) to see how a question page would look at different viewports. However, since not all pages are responsive yet, asking a question and many moderator or review activities will not work well and you'll need to expand the window.

## What does this mean for you?

1. If you're not in a team, then no change.
2. If you're in a team, not all pages are responsive, but many are. See the list below for more details.
3. Only Stackoverflow.com is affected for now. MSO and other network sites will NOT be responsive.
4. The changes are most obvious on smaller view ports. You'll start seeing changes under 1200px.
5. If you like to use full screen windows on higher resolution displays, then things will look unchanged. There is a max limit for the width of the content area. This maintains reasonable line lengths for readability.
6. If you find a bug that you think is connected to this change, then post it to meta  with a full description and image. Include the browser you're using and tag the post [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)).
7. If the bug is serious and makes it difficult to use the site, then you can disable responsive on your device by clicking "Disable Responsive" in the footer.

## Responsive pages or elements

- Question pages
- Question lists
- Users and tags lists
- Search results
- Privileges
- Help center
- Top bar and footer
- and a few other miscellaneous pages

### Non-responsive pages

Pretty much everything else is non-responsive. This includes Ask a Question, profile pages and most moderator and review pages.

## Next steps

We are working on making Ask a Question and some of the other pages responsive. Later this month we will turn on left nav and responsive design on for all users on MSE. This will extend the testing and will allow more people to provide feedback.

Comment: Shouldn't this be featured? It seems rather important to me.

Comment: @MEE The number of users actually impacted is somewhat small for now since it is limited to teams users. When we push to MSE later this month that will definitely be featured.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Probably we need a new mod-only tag on StackOverflow [team-featured] for posts only featured for team users. ;). And it will probably be hot soon so that this would be seen by team users anyway

Comment: +1 for the work put in it. Kudos to the team.

Comment: I read "and most moderator and review pages." ... and then I continue to read "on making Ask a Question and some of the other pages responsive" ... I hope the mod pages are included, fingers crossed. thanks for this!!

Comment: @BhargavRao ultimately they will be included, but not sure yet on the timing. So many details to work out.

Comment: Was the target audience of "people in teams" chosen specifically to make the number of people small for now?

Comment: @DavidG While responsiveness is nice for everyone, it is critical when the left nav is enabled. Teams users are the only people who are currently seeing the left nav, so they are the first group to see responsive. Both left nav and responsive will be flighted on MSE later this month for broader review by the community.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. I look forward to seeing how it looks when we get to test it out!

Comment: Thanks for this information.  I hope that moderator functions will work before the rollout moves beyond SO (where mods are already affected) and MSE (where there are no mods).

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to fix the left sidebar's position? That's pretty standard for left sidebars.

Changing the css with

```
#content {margin-left:200px;}
.left-sidebar {position: fixed;}
```

works for the homepage, but moves and distracts the whole content on sites where SO doesn't follow the homepage's design.

Comment: It's unlikely that the left sidebar will *currently* be too tall for anyone but there's a good chance, if they keep adding things to it, that it will eventually require page scroll to view the entire thing on smaller screen formats.