# Incorrect display of bronze badge with 2 digit count

Tags: bug, design

I'm unsure if this qualifies as a bug, but at least on my display, part of the bronze badge gets cut off.

Although just an aesthetic issue, it's bothering nonetheless.

As pictured, the right hand side of the circle gets cut off:

[image]

System:

- Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OSX 10.13.4 (17E199)
- MBP Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013
- Zoom Level 100%

I don't seem to have the problem with a single digit bronze badge count:

[image]

Both pictures where taken from the top bar.

Comment: What browser, what zoom level, and what OS? Note that zoom levels other than 100% are not supported.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OS X, using Firefox 59.

Comment: added the specs to the question

Comment: Where was this screenshot taken? The top bar? (I guess so because of the bronze-colored 11; that makes it a little harder to reproduce.)

Comment: @Glorfindel 
Yes, the top bar. I don't have the problem in other communities where I have a single digit  bronze badge count

Comment: Do you have by any chance your fonts overridden? `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif` is what is expected there.

Comment: @rene I never overrode the standard fonts. Can you point out to me how to find the setting?

Comment: No, I've not done this myself, only recall reports from users who had done that. That was unix boxes, IIRC and it was done at the OS level.

Comment: Like I said, I never tempered with the vanilla SO ui

Comment: Might be that you only have this problem on SO main due to the responsive design for Teams users that rolled out Friday: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367724/responsive-design-is-enabled-for-teams-users

Comment: Probably related to [the different comparability levels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-right) and the .CSS for the webpage `.topbar-flair .badge1,.topbar .topbar-links .topbar-flair .badge2,.topbar .topbar-links .topbar-flair .badge3{padding-right:3px}.topbar` - On Android, using Chrome or Firefox, the badge3 dots are round (even for Rene's 3 digit count, above).

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on FF 60 x64, Windows 10, 130% zoom, window 1263 pixels wide. At 100% zoom I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I can also reproduce it for zoom 110%, Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 8.1. No issue with zoom 100%.

Comment: I can only reproduce with zoom lvl 120,130 and 170-190%, using FF 60.0 (64b) on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with a 1920 pixel screen.

Comment: For me the silver badge is getting cut

Comment: I can "reproduce" this on IE 11.431.16299.0 on zoom level 160% except I lose the right hand side of the silver circle and the left hand side of the bronze circle

Comment: Very important indeed.

Comment: I can repro at 75% ,80%, 120% and 135% in Chrome (65.0.3325.181 x64)

Comment: I can reproduce at 100% on Chrome,  66.0.3359.139 (windows 7). Fixes itself at any other zoom level. Also changing the width of .badge1 .badge2 and .badge3 to 7px (from 6px) predictably fixes