# Wacky layout bug: Right sidebar appears below answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I am a user of Teams (née Channels) which means my Stack Overflow has the left sidebar, with the various issues and aesthetic mishaps that this introduces.  However, after the weekend, I see a new glitch: The content which used to be displayed on the right of a question is now displayed below the answers for me.

[image: Screen shot illustrating the problem]

(The question in the screen shot is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105175/equals-vs-space-o-value-vs-o-value-in-nix-command-line-programs-best) and you'll notice how the "asked 4 years, 5 months ago" etc and the "featured on meta" box is stuff that traditionally were displayed to the right of the question at the top of the page.)

This is Chrome on MacOS; JavaScript reports viewport dimensions 904x523 for this window.

Maximizing the window technically resolves this issue, but is unacceptable.
I need to have multiple windows visible on my screen.

Comment: Its not just in case of specific Question. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsTk6.png) is featured in meta at the bottom of the page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a part of the responsiveness changes. You can review details on this in the following meta posts ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367724/responsive-design-is-enabled-for-teams-users), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes)). This is a v0.1 release. We will be improving this behavior over time.

For example:

- items from the right bar (now below the last answer on smaller viewports) could utilize the full width of the content column.
- Or, some of the more important items could be relocated to a higher profile location.

That said, this is working as intended.

Comment: Whaddya know, I had actually read the announcements about the responsive design effort, but this was still surprising and slightly annoying. Does "responsive" inherently require "three-column" or could the left sidebar actually be merged with the right?

Comment: @tripleee left nav can't really be merged with the right side bar. They serve completely different purposes. There is nothing inherent about responsive other than the layout needs to adapt to the size of the viewport. Our layout adjusts by adapting the number of columns and the location of various elements. Things have to go somewhere when the viewport gets smaller. We are trying to keep the most critical components in view.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarifying -- I just discovered that I previously unconsciously learned to use scroll to bottom to get near the answer box. This no longer works. Also the waster screen real estate is a bummer. Having unimportant things spill into unused space would be nice instead of having them create lots of new unused space.

Comment: The joke at the end about this working as intended made me chuckle. Good one :)