# The new design is completely unusable on mobile in Desktop mode

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design

## The problem

The new design completely broke the appearance of the website on mobile (Firefox on Android) rendering it completely unusable. It is one long strip with the menu, then many, questions, lots of scrolling and many questions, lots of scrolling, featured on meta, favourite tags, scrolling, hot network posts, scrolling, the bottom menu.

The most important buttons (favourite tags) are completely buried somewhere on the bottom.

I am using the desktop site, not mobile. It behaves like a bad mobile webpage anyway.

## Steps to reproduce

- Open the Stack Overflow site on a mobile device
- Click `Request Desktop Site` in the browser menu

## Screenshot from my Desktop with UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:57.0) Gecko/57.0 Firefox/57.0

<sup>click image for larger version</sup>

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I have no idea how to make a screenshot of something that long.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the issue, it seems to only apply when you have desktop mode enabled?

Comment: My guess is that it looks like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310916/253521

Comment: Apart from that is ugly as hell ... what were they thinking about? :D

Comment: Cannot reproduce on the iPhone but I'm still on iOS 10.3.3.

Comment: The Hero banner that's displayed if you're not logged in has issues in Opera Mini on iOS but the menu and question list look OK there too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wacky layout bug: Right sidebar appears below answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367849/wacky-layout-bug-right-sidebar-appears-below-answers)

Comment: Can someone ensmallen thescreenshot and link to the full size? That's a lot of scrolling. :/ You can disable (for now) the responsive design if you like. There's a link in the footer under "STACK OVERFLOW". :)

Comment: *most important buttons* I thought you were here for the good questions? Anyway, if all goes well I expect some of the tab features that were available in new-nav will come back, allowing you to organize your tabs as you wish which would bring your tag choices at the top of the page.

Comment: Also, this is currently known and sort of a hack-y work around until they get the mobile version up and running... they're working on redoing the design but I think this answer on MSE and the comments from Joe Friend explain it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310916/284336

Comment: Printing is terrible too.....you get all the side columns, and a thin sliver with the Q+A......so no way to archive or even print a question with its answer in a sensible way...it was even marginal before the re-design....but now unacceptable.

Comment: Both questions are about the new design, but this question is specific to the mobile mode while the other not. I think the problems are entirely different (btw, the new design didn't even exist at the time of the orig candidate). Not dupe.

Comment: @peterh Actually, this question appears to be about the desktop mode on a mobile device. The new design had been rolled out to Teams users when the proposed dupe was posted. I don't think it's a dupe either, just saying...

Comment: @peterh and Mike McCaughan: I'm fairly sure the same underlying issue is involved. I, for one, first noticed this  "bottom bar" awkwardness about a week ago, when the new layout was rolled out on Meta, while using the desktop mode on mobile Chrome.

Comment: (@peterh In any case, I have retracted my close vote -- Joe Friend's answer justifies the question.)

Comment: Note tat you can reproduce this in a desktop browser by simply resizing the window to be narrow enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The responsive design is primarily focused on desktop use for this iteration, [as mentioned on the MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/354333). The assumption is that most users are currently using the mobile skin (see footer for "mobile" link) when on a phone. However, if you do prefer the desktop view on your mobile device, then there is an option in the footer to "Disable Responsiveness". This will give you what you want for now.

Ultimately we aim to make the responsive site work well on mobile and replace the mobile skin. Your feedback will be useful for when we work on that.

Comment: Also, most mobile browsers (e.g. mobile Chrome) have a "request desktop site" option that falsifies a larger viewport, so once the "Disable Responsiveness" option goes away, you can use that to force a desktop-like viewport.

Comment: how is this designed for "desktop use" when half the page is empty on a modern desktop?

Comment: @rogerdeuce How should the empty space be used, though? The obvious answers, stretching the center column, isn't necessarily a good idea, as long lines of text can be uncomfortable to read.

Comment: @duplode over one third of my screen is empty. Fill some of that space with the center column information.  As it stands, my large screen is being treated like I have a small screen.

Comment: @rogerdeuce What resolution are you using? On 1080p the page is exactly the right width.

Comment: The problem with these links being in the footer is that's a looooong way to scroll.

Comment: @Clonkex Yes, it is very bizarre to see all of these "there's too much/not enough space" complaints that seem to assume everyone has the same monitor/screen size and the same resolution.

Answer (score 7):

I have a bone to pick with this.

I *like* the layout on mobile. I've been mostly using the desktop theme on mobile for years now, because most of the moderator tooling is either unavailable or less functional in the mobile theme. And... It kinda sucked. I don't have a big fancy "Phablet" phone; I have a LG G5 running LineageOS; it's decent, but hardly allows me to read anything without zooming in.

Now I can read. And moderate. And, if I scroll furiously, view stuff like related questions, the bulletin, and tag prefs... None of which were really functional in the mobile theme and required zooming and careful targeting on the old desktop theme.

Granted, I'd be happier if these auxilliary functions were accessible *without* furious scrolling - maybe in [yet another hamburger menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369486/mcstackiconoverflow)? - but right now, this is still a serious step up from what I had a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

The new design is not optimized for the main purpose, in the desktop version. As simple as that!

The view is cluttered with a lot of non useful information.

And the middle section in the page reserved for the answers is just too narrow and too small. Makes you even more frustrated because you are having a problem and still can't find the solution.