# Favorite tags and other right side stuff

Tags: discussion, tag-watching, hot-questions, design

With the new navigation when viewing on my iPad, the right side stuff doesn’t show at all unless I hold it landscape, which I never do.

But I use the favorite tags view all the time. Or did. (I also use the hot questions list and featured post stuff regularly). Is that still reachable easily in the default upright view?

Comment: You should check if it has [gone to the bottom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367849/wacky-layout-bug-right-sidebar-appears-below-answers) or not

Comment: ugh.  really?  with all that real estate on the left?  also the fact that the left side isn't anchored.... i know there's a thread on the new UI.  i guess my favorites etc are at the bottom.

Comment: Nice to know that you use these heavily. We've seen similar behavior in user research. We are working on a feature where you can add things like this to the left nav.